# How do we handle multiple answers to a question from the same user?

Tags: discussion

We have this question:

[Is there a grandfather paradox in Endgame?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99656/is-there-a-grandfather-paradox-in-endgame/99776)

Where a user appears to believe we're a forum and has done multiple answers:

- https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99776/44698
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99785/44698
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99832/44698
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99834/44698

I've edited the initial question and merged the answers together, was that the correct thing to do?

Also, assuming my previous action was correct, what vote should we use to remove the duplicate answers or should I request a moderator's invention?

Comment: I haven't seen the specific film yet, so I don't feel confident or willing to analyse the specific answers thoroughly (nor to provide an answer to this meta question, yet), but generally speaking, it depends. Just smashing all the answers into one big post one after the other might not be the best outcome either. Rather than that it should be analyzed which answers are really just comments, which are just reiterating stuff from other answers, and which might even be able to stand on their own for expressing contrary viewpoints. However, I agree *something* should be done about them indeed.